# Custom background for Text View Using Xml drawable file

Tags: android, xml, background, textview

[image]

I want to make a textview background like in the screenshot. I have a xml file that can make rectangular background like in the screenshot but i am not able to do that below corner styling. I dont know what thing can change this.
Here is my xml file that can give a rectangular background to my textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
<stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/orange" />

<solid android:color="@color/orange" />

<padding
       android:left="1dp"
       android:right="1dp"
       android:top="1dp" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here would be to make a [nine-patch image](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html). Roman Nurik has made a really nice [nine-patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) that you can use. Then you just set the image as the background and it will stretch like you think it should.

Comment: I tried with nine patch image but it is not stretching according to my textview size :(

Comment: What does your nine patch look like?

Comment: i Uploaded my this image in that generator and made different screens sizes 9 patch image with that generator then putting these images in my drawables folder and setting as background in my textview. But my textview goes here and there and not fitting full inside background

Comment: Here's the link to the generated nine patches: blob:https%3A//romannurik.github.io/157569be-953a-4b40-8248-ee89efa2b6ec

Comment: Thats exactly what i want. How you did that? Your text is fitting in it

Comment: let me try your settings